# Parent Dialog Closes When Child Dialog is Closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that I open using ParentForm.ShowDialog().

Inside this form I call:

```
using (var form = new ChildForm())
{
    var result = form.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.Cancelled = false;
    }
}
```

I'm getting odd behavior when the child dialog is closed, the parent (calling) form also closes.

**Why is this happening and how do I stop it?**

*I have a current solution that prevents the closing of the parent form by using the ParentForm_FormClosing event and a Boolean, but it feels like an over complicated solution*

Comment: In which event do you call the code above?

Comment: The code above is called through either a button click event, a double click event on a datagridview cell (CellMouseDoubleClick), or a datagridview keydown event (when the key press is the enter key).

Comment: What is the value for the property DialogResult on the button?

Comment: form.ShowDialog(this);

Comment: @Steve Ahhhhh, I didn't realize I had set that or that it would have an effect. Thank you, it looks like this will solve it for me.

Comment: What's `this.Cancelled`? and how are you using it?  That's not a default property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form opened modally is closed when you set the property DialogResult to anything but DialogResult.None. The common practice to close a modal form is to set the DialogResult property of one or more buttons to some value of the same named enum. In that way, when the form engine sees a call to a click event handler checks the value of the DialogResult of the clicked button and, if nothing change that value, it closes the form when the click event handler ends returning that enum value to the caller.

So, you probably have copy/paste that button leaving the original DialogResult property unchanged and clicking that button will trigger the closure of the hosting form.

Of course before closing the hosting form, the engine will call the button click event in which you open a modal dialog and this suspends everything until you close the child form. At that point the code exits the click event and the form engine continue closing your parent form returning to the caller the value of the DialogResult property of the button.

If you don't want to automtically close the hosting form then you can set the form's DialogResult in code with

```
 this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
```

or change the value of the button's DialogResult property